# Plot in Seaborn 2 probability denisty functions on one figure

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

I'm trying to plot two probability density functions on one figure(so that they overlap).

```
 import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy
import seaborn as sns
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
data = [0,0,1,2,2,2,2,1,2,3,0,5,4,5,4,6,2,2,5,4,6,3,2,5,4,3,7,-1,0]
scaler = MinMaxScaler()
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['Numbers'])
X = numpy.asarray(data)
X=X.reshape(-1,1)
standardized_data = scaler.fit_transform(X)

normal_data = np.random.normal(loc=0.0, scale=1.0, size=len(df))
sns.displot(normal_data, kind='kde')
sns.displot(standardized_data, kind='kde')

plt.show()
```

Comment: You need `sns.kdeplot(...)` instead of `sns.displot(...)`. `ax = sns.kdeplot(normal_data, color='red'); sns.kdeplot(standardized_data, color='blue')`

Comment: Note that in matplotlib, the term `figure` is meant for the surrounding plot containing one or more subplots. A subplot is often referred to as `ax`.

Comment: Your code raises an `IndexError` when I copy and paste it to try to help.

Comment: I'm sorry, I edited it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
sns.displot(
    {"normal": normal_data, "standardized": standardized_data.squeeze()},
    kind='kde'
)
```

[image]